# Is a linked list an abstract data type or a data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

Because it seems to be clearly defined as node which contains some data and and address to the next node, I would have assumed it is a data structure and not an abstract data type.

However in this entry on [data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) by Wikipedia, it is not included.  For purposes of learning , I would have expected it to be next in importance to arrays, but it is not listed except under *See Also*

Here is the wikipedia for  [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type).

Here is a seemingly more accurate wikipedia entry for a [list of data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures)

Comment: As an ADT, the linked list describes its features. As a data structure, it is an implementation you can use.

Comment: A linked list is an implementation type, not an ADT.  In most cases, a plain "linked list" refers to a singly (or simple) linked list, which would be a data structure.

Comment: I think you might find this link helpful: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/147886/when-programmers-talk-about-data-structures-what-are-they-referring-to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know LinkedList is not a ADT. It is data structure. Check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures it contains the linkedlist.

Linkedlist can be singly linked or doubly linked.

Comment: Excellent link to support the definition I made up as such:

Comment: `Because there is not much consistency, I'm going to suggest this - If there are multiple implementations - than it is an Abstract Data Type. For example a Queue can be implemented as an array or a linked list so it is an ADT. An array can not be implemented in multiple ways, so it is a data structure. There needs to be a consistent way to communicate this and I think this works well.`

Comment: Can you find something more formal that differentiates the two?

Comment: try this one http://abrickshort.wordpress.com/2005/03/06/abstract-data-types-vs-data-structures/ it elaborate well

Answer (score 3):

A Java `LinkedList` is a concrete class that implements the structure where each node is linked to one or more neighbours by links.

The Abstract Data Type Wikipedia article you link to uses the word `abstract` in a completely different meaning. There it means that the data type is defined in an abstract way - much like I described the Java LinkedList above (*implements the structure where each node is linked to one or more neighbours by links*).

In Java, abstract data types are types that cannot actually be instantiated - they can only be extended. The use of the word `abstract` here is not connected to the use of the word Abstract in `ADT`.

Comment: nope ADT is not a Java term, it is a CS term.  Your answer is off laterally speaking by about 90 degrees.

Comment: from the context of my question, I am not referring to the Java keyword `abstract`.  Hence neither should the answer.  +1 any ways.

Comment: The question has `java` tag. In java you do have `LinkedList` class which is a *concrete* class. `LinkedList` indeed is an implementation of the concept `each node is linked to one or more neighbours by links. Each node having data and a link to another node of same type`. I feel answer is not off the track. **LinkedList is a data structure.** It is not an ADT like `Stack` or `Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        Stack s = new Stack<>();
List l = new LinkedList<>();
s.push(45);
s.push("str");
l.add("hi");
l.add(4);
//s.push("String");
```

List is ADT, LinkedList is Datastructure.

Stack is ADT and Data Structure because it works with object and no need of concrete implementation.